# Nesting of classes in Javascript in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project that involves people 'highlighting' certain words by clicking on them. In order to do this, I need to make a certain transformation on classes, described here:

`<span class='x y'>lorem</span>`

`<span class='x y z'>ipsum</span>`

I want this to become:

```
<span class="x y">
    lorem
    <span class="z">
        ipsum
    </span>
</span>
```

The classes could be a combination of many different classes, so simply hardcoding this is out of the picture. I can use jQuery to achieve this, but unfortunately I can't find a way how).

EDIT: Sorry, my question might be a bit unclear:

I need to find some algorithm that will make this nested transformation for me. I thought of a combination of using next() functions on each of the classes, but that seems highly inefficient.

Comment: I really don't know what your question is?

Comment: Would `y` be nested inside a `x` element?

Comment: Added some clarification!

Comment: By the logic of what you're asking for, @AlexThomas is right. If it's a case of splitting up classes and embedding accordingly, `y` should be a 'child' of `x`.

Comment: It's not entirely a case of splitting up classes. When the classnames of the two elements are same (in this example the classes x and y are found both in the first and the second element), the difference between the classes (z in this case) would need to be nested.